# Update row with data from another row in different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to MySQL and not too sure how can I update row from another table while checking if logged in user is the same:

`Telefonist='".$_SESSION["UserName"]."`

And also I need to check if date is the same so it gets to right person on right date in a row:

```
log.Datum=telefonisti_podaci.Datum
```

here I am trying to count all 1s and enter sum from table1 to table2 in specific place.

Code:

```
$sql_zapis_do30 = "UPDATE telefonisti_podaci
SET `Total tura do 30` = (Select COUNT(*) `Ture do 30` from log,telefonisti_podaci WHERE `Ture do 30` is not null AND `Ture do 30`=1 AND log.Datum=telefonisti_podaci.Datum )
WHERE `Telefonist`='".$_SESSION["UserName"]."'";
CustomQuery($sql_zapis_do30);
```

I get error:

```
You can't specify target table 'telefonisti_podaci' for update in FROM clause
```

Thanks

Comment: is `Total tura do 30` your actual column name? Read up on the function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: many duplicates on SO for `You can't specify target table *** for update in FROM clause` http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=You+can%27t+specify+target+table (hint: when selecting a table to insert into the same table, the select table needs to done with an alias)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it like this:

```
$sql_zapis_do30 = "UPDATE telefonisti_podaci
SET `Total tura do 30` = (Select COUNT(`Ture do 30`) from log WHERE `Telefonist`='".$_SESSION["UserName"]."' AND `Ture do 30`=1 AND `Datum`='".$datum_danas."')
WHERE `Telefonist`='".$_SESSION["UserName"]."' AND `Datum`='".$datum_danas."'";
```

And it works for now
Thanks